# AsyncTask is showing all list items in single row in Listview

Tags: android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask for showing the Arraylist items in Listview. But AsyncTask shows all Arraylist items in a single Listview item. can anybody suggest what's wrong here?

The code:

```
package com.example.ganesh.async;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressBar pb;
ListView l;
String s[] = {"MUMBAI, PUNE, DELHI, BANGLORE, KOLKATA, MUMBAI, PUNE, DELHI, BANGLORE, KOLKATA"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    l.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>()));
    new myTask().execute();
}

class myTask extends AsyncTask{

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    int counter = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        aa = (ArrayAdapter<String>) l.getAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object[] params) {
       for(int k=0; k<s.length; k++)
       {
           String po = s[k];
           publishProgress(po);
       }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object[] values) {
        aa.add(values[0].toString());
        counter++;
        pb.setProgress(((counter/s.length)*10));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," Added "+values[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {

    }
}
}
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, the size of your string array is one.

Change this to....

```
String s[] = {"MUMBAI, PUNE, DELHI, BANGLORE, KOLKATA, MUMBAI, PUNE, DELHI, BANGLORE, KOLKATA"};
```

this

```
String s[] = {"MUMBAI", "PUNE", "DELHI", "BANGLORE", "KOLKATA", "MUMBAI", "PUNE", "DELHI", "BANGLORE", "KOLKATA"};
```